# Fetch Autosys Job status through API

Tags: python, request, autosys

API is displaying all the attribute values of a job (like status, job name, instance, start time, etc).
I just want to know in post method how should i write the code so that it can fetch the status from api and display output.

```
url="http://some.api.com"
def get_job_status():
  try:
     response=requests.post(url)
     print(response.status_code)
     if response.status_code==200:
     // `enter code here`
     dict_data=response.json()
     print(dict_data["status'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Load text into json object and fetch with keys

```
import requests
url = "http://some.api.com"
def get_job_status():
  response = requests.request("POST", url)
  if response.status_code == 200:
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    job_name = json_data["name"]
    job_status = json_data["status"]
  else:
    return "Error with Request"
```